# How to scale an animation in blender

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an animation in blender, but its very small in dimensions. I have to scale it to a factor of around 10. However, I just realized that just scaling an object won't actually scale the whole animation ( while rendering ). Is there anyway with which I can scale the whole animation ( including each keyframes )?

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, I dont want to extend the moving area of the animation. I want to increase the dimensions of the image used in animation. When I am trying to scale up the object in 3D view, it does scale the animated object placed on the scene, however, when I play the animation, the scaled dimensions aren't preserved.

[image: Picture1: The FBX object I am using at the scene is quite small as seen in the picture 1]

I hope its a bit clear now what I want to do.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean scale over time?

Comment: @JaxXxon no, i meant to scale from the start itself. The fbx i have have quite tiny dimensions, and i have to project them over to a surface, where at present they are hardly noticeable. Thus, have to scale them up to match surface size

Comment: So, instead ,for example, an object would move 10 meters instead of 1 meter?

Comment: @JaxXxon Sorry for the confusion, I dont want to extend the moving area of the animation. I want to increase the dimensions of the image used in animation. When I am trying to scale up the object in 3D view, it does scale the animated object placed on the scene, however, when I play the animation, the scaled dimensions aren't preserved.

Comment: @JaxXxon Please refer to the question edit section

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me what is happening.
Please share a blend if you can.

Comment: What do you mean by "the image used in animation"?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the graph editor,

- place the 2D cursor at the origin (the arrow on the screenshot below),
- choose the 2D cursor as pivot <kbd>.</kbd> (the rectangle below)
- select all <kbd>A</kbd> (or only the keys you want <kbd>B</kbd>)
- scale <kbd>S</kbd> on the vertical axis <kbd>Y</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks however, I believe I wasnt clear in describing my problem. Please refer to the edit section of the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling an inamation can be done in the graph editor. First select the object you wish to scale the animation for. Then open a graph editor in one of your views. Then follow the steps in attached image. I used a cube which was animated on the Z-axis in my example.

[image: scale animation in graph editor]

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have managed to do what I wanted to achieve. I used export fbx option and increased the scaling size, and it seems to work.

However, if there exists some other better way please share.
Also, while exporting FBX, some animated objects are rotated randomly and they loose their original x,y,z coordinates in the space. I believe it has something to do with the two parameter 'forward' and 'up' in the export fbx option.

Comment: I loved your solution to this problem! Thanks for coming back here to share.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty and parent your animated object to it.

Then scale your empty, it will scale your animated object too.

Comment: Could you illustrate the steps to achieve this?